# MAUI: Binding to my viewmodel throws an error before compilation (prop not found)

Tags: xaml, maui, compiled-bindings

I have a simple view model:

```cs
public List<DisplayModel> Items { get; set; } = new List<DisplayModel>();

public class DisplayModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Prop { get; set; }   
}
```

In my view, I have this collection view:

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Grid ColumnSpacing="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label TextColor="White" FontSize="18" FontFamily="WuerthExtraBold"  Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Label TextColor="White" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold"   Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="{Binding Prop}"/>
                </Grid>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

but as soon as I hit compile, it tell me that the property name or prop arent found:

[image]

I can bind to that list, but just not with those properties. What is going on?

Comment: Apart from the missing `x:DataType`, which likely is the cause when [compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings) are used, are you sure this would even work? Your `Items` list isn't observable, do you trigger any `PropertyChanged` events manually to notify the UI of any changes to that list?

Comment: thanks for the input, this is just a sample,. usually i use ObservableCollection

Comment: Okay, just making sure, because the code as it is won't be able to reflect any changes in the UI, especially since you initialize the list without elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a [DataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0)

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:DisplayModel">
```

Comment: This just tells me that local:displaymodel wasnt found...

Comment: did your read the docs I linked to?  You will need to declare the appropriate `xmlns` for your code.  I just used `local` as an example, you did not provide enough code for me to know what would work for your case

Comment: i am trying to work my way through, i think i got it. ill come back to you asap! thanks

Comment: Alright i got it; i neede to add the namespace to my model like so: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WuerthScanner.Bin.ViewModels"